# Magento price change depending on currency

Tags: php, currency, magento-1.6

Situation: Im creating Magento webstore with multiple currencies (website for each) and have price scope set to website.

Problem: If I change price in one currency the other does not change. When i set product scope to multiple websites (currencies) the product in each currency has the same price.

The questions are:

- How can i set scope between currencies by converting price from initial currency to each of the new currencies.
- How to update price in each website (currency) by changing price only in one, base currency or maybe in global scope (all websites).